# Sphinx documentation inside a Flask running web application

Tags: flask, python-sphinx

I've locally built static Sphinx documentations (using `make html`).

I wish now to integrate the Sphinx files into my webapp that runs with Flask. From the Flask running application, I simply mean to include an hyperlink towards the Sphinx documentation, that will serve as help for the application.

[Websupport](http://sphinx-doc.org/web/quickstart.html) seems the way to follow, but it's not clear to me how I should bridge the Flask framework to the Sphinx files.

Thanks for any help,

Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just handle it with your web server, the same way you handle the `/static` directory in Flask.  For example if you used Apache as your production web server, you might add

```
Alias /documentation /location/of/sphinx/html
<Directory /location/of/sphinx/html>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

to your Apache site configuration, so then you could just link directly to `http://yoursite.com/documentation` to access the Sphinx files, avoiding Flask altogether.

Answer (score 13):

Other solutions nicely omit the `Flask` object initialization, which lead me to bang my head against the wall for a while.

Without touching the Sphinx project structure at all, here's the solution that worked for me:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/', static_folder='_build/html/')


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def serve_sphinx_docs(path='index.html'):
    return app.send_static_file(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And below is the file structure of the project, where `<doc>` represents the rst files I actually wrote for the documentation, and `app.py` is the file containing the Flask app code above.

```
.
├── Makefile
├── _build
│   ├── doctrees
│   │   ├── index.doctree
│   │   ├── <doc>.doctree
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── <doc>.doctree
│   └── html
│       ├── _images
│       ├── _modules
│       │   ├── index.html
│       │   └── <package name>
│       │       └── ...
│       ├── _sources
│       │   ├── <doc>.rst.txt
│       │   ├── ...
│       │   └── <doc>.rst.txt
│       ├── _static
│       │   ├── ajax-loader.gif
│       │   ├── alabaster.css
│       │   └── ...
│       ├── genindex.html
│       ├── index.html
│       ├── objects.inv
│       ├── py-modindex.html
│       ├── search.html
│       ├── searchindex.js
│       ├── <doc>.html
│       ├── ...
│       └── <doc>.html
├── _static
│   ├── custom.css
│   └── <myimage>.gif
├── _templates
├── app.py
├── conf.py
├── index.rst
├── make.bat
├── <doc>.rst
├── ...
└── <doc>.rst
```

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the `_build/html` folder from your docs to a `doc` folder in your flask `static` directory, and serve them with the following rule:

```
@app.route('/doc/<dir>/<filename>', defaults={'static': True})
def doc(dir='',filename='index.html'):
    path = join(dir,filename)
    return app.send_static_file(path)
```

Comment: Where do you get "join" from? Maybe use something like "os.path.join(dir, filename)"

Comment: This also leads to a 404 unless "dir" and "filename" are specified.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases you do not want to expose your docs to all users so configuring at the Apache or Nginx level is not an option. The following worked for me:

```
@app.route('/docs', defaults = {'filename': 'index.html'})
@app.route('/docs/<path:filename>')
@login_required
def web_docs(filename):
    path = os.path.join('docs/html', filename)
    return app.send_static_file(path)
```

Comment: This works for me using sphinx. However, the page does not have any of the CSS styling when I use the '/docs' route, but when I use the full path to index.html directly I do get the CSS. Wondering if you have any ideas on this.. all the style files are in 'docs/html/_static'

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've seen the `Flask.send_static_file` method requires that the file resides within the static directory. Sub directories are not supported using this method.

To serve a file from any location use the [Flask.send_from_directory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory) method.

Example:

```py
import flask
from flask import send_from_directory


app = Flask(
    import_name=__name__
    )


@app.route('/docs/', defaults={'filename': 'index.html'})
@app.route('/docs/<path:filename>')
def docs(filename) -> flask.send_from_directory:
    docs_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'docs', 'build', 'html')

    return send_from_directory(directory=docs_dir, path=filename)
```

The example assumes `docs\build\html\` exists in the same directory as the python file. Change `docs_dir` as needed.

Additionally, without appending a trailing backslash to the default route, the page did not render properly, therefore I changed the default route to `/docs/`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `BUILDDIR` path in sphinx Makefile

```
BUILDDIR      = app/static/docs
```

add flask routes

```py
@app.get('/docs/')
@app.get('/docs/<path:filename>')
def get_docs(filename='index.html'):
    path = os.path.join('docs/html', filename)
    return app.send_static_file(path)
```

Build the sphinx documentation.

```sh
$ make html
```

You can browse to http://127.0.0.1:5000/docs for sphinx documentation page. All the sphinx docs static files will be served under this route. You can also add Flask Authentication to the route if needed.

Test Versions:

- Flask: 2.0.2
- Sphinx: 4.3.1